# org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient thows Unresolved requirement error when my eclipse RCP is lauched

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, httpclient, eclipse-rcp, apache-commons-codec

Immediately after launching the I am getting an exception.
I'm working on an Eclipse RCP application and encountering an unresolved dependency related to the httpclient plugin. The error message indicates:

```
Package: org.apache.commons.codec.binary
Missing Version: [1.13.0,1.14.0)
```

Stacktrace:
org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient [1090]
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.commons.codec.binary; version="[1.13.0,1.14.0)"

OSGI:
When I check org.apache.commons.codec in osgi console both org.apache.commons.codec 1.13 and 1.14 are in INSTALLED state not RESOLVED.

- Uninstalling org.apache.commons.codec version 1.14.0 resolves the issue for the httpclient plugin.
- The httpclient plugin works correctly in other similar Eclipse RCP environments.
- org.apache.commons.codec 1.13 is required by JDK 11 itself which was recently changed from JDK 8. by JDK Mission Control

Need to know:
What is causing this dependency conflict with org.apache.commons.codec.binary version 1.14.0?
Are there alternative solutions besides uninstalling version 1.14.0?
How can I ensure compatibility between the httpclient plugin and org.apache.commons.codec in my specific RCP environment?

Comment: Your question is hard to read only showing parts of what have been logged. `[1.13.0,1.14.0)` means 1.13 or higher, but lower than 1.14. So, the bundle/plugin that requires `org.apache.commons.codec.binary` of version `[1.13.0,1.14.0)` (`org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient`?), does not work with the current version of `org.apache.commons.codec.binary` 1.14 and has to be upgraded. Better build your RCP application based on the latest simultaneous release (`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest` contains `org.apache.commons.codec` of version 1.14 only).